# Game crashes when I try to destroy a b2Body, what should I do?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

```
"Assertion failed: (m_bodyCount < m_bodyCapacity), function Add, file libs/Box2D/Dynamics/b2Island.h, line 65."
```

That is what it the crash leaves in the console.

```
[self removeChild:(CCSprite*)body->GetUserData() cleanup:YES];

body->SetTransform(b2Vec2(30, 30), 0); //moving the body out of the scene so it doesnt collide anymore!

 world->DestroyBody(body);
```

I think im doing the right stuff..

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) b2Body *body;
```

Here is how i "make it" a property

I dont understand why it doesnt work, "body" is a proper pointer because I can retrieve infromation from the bodys UserData like tags that are set in the creatin of the body, so that shouldnt be a problem.. Do anyone know whats wrong with my code?

Thank you.

Edited in:

```
-(void) tick: (ccTime) dt //Main loop
{

if (ballFired) {
    Magnet *aMagnet = [magnetArray objectAtIndex:0];

    world->DestroyBody(aMagnet.body); //It crashes here!
}



int32 velocityIterations = 8;
int32 positionIterations = 1;

// Instruct the world to perform a single step of simulation. It is
// generally best to keep the time step and iterations fixed.
world->Step(dt, velocityIterations, positionIterations);


//Iterate over the bodies in the physics world
for (b = world->GetBodyList(); b; b = b->GetNext())
{
    if (b->GetUserData() != NULL) {
        //Synchronize the AtlasSprites position and rotation with the corresponding body
        CCSprite *myActor = (CCSprite*)b->GetUserData();
        myActor.position = CGPointMake( b->GetPosition().x * PTM_RATIO, b>GetPosition().y * PTM_RATIO);
        myActor.rotation = -1 * CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(b->GetAngle());
    }   
    }




}
```

Isnt this outside the world step?

Edit 2:

```
        ContactListener::ContactListener(){};

         void ContactListener::BeginContact(b2Contact* contact)
        {
        // Box2d objects that collided
       b2Fixture* fixtureA = contact->GetFixtureA();


       b2Fixture* fixtureB = contact->GetFixtureB();
       CCSprite* actorA = (CCSprite*) fixtureA->GetBody()->GetUserData();
       CCSprite* actorB = (CCSprite*)  fixtureB->GetBody()->GetUserData();



      if(actorA == nil || actorB == nil) return;

    b2WorldManifold* worldManifold = new b2WorldManifold();
    contact->GetWorldManifold(worldManifold);


      Kollisjon *kollisjon = [Kollisjon sharedKollisjon];

     if (actorA.tag == 1) {

    NSLog(@"OK1");

    kollisjon.kollidertBody = fixtureB->GetBody();

    kollisjon.world->DestroyBody(kollisjon.kollidertBody); //Isnt this ok?

    }

    else if (actorB.tag == 1) {

       NSLog(@"OK2");


       kollisjon.kollidertBody = fixtureA->GetBody();

       kollisjon.world->DestroyBody(kollisjon.kollidertBody); //Isnt this ok?

    } 


    }
```

Is it not outside the timestep? Please help me here...

Thank you

Comment: An assertion is being triggered because there is more bodies than capacity! Thats all I have for you since I am not experienced with that API.

Comment: Are you trying to do this in the middle of a timestep or something? Using threads maybe? My guess is you are overwriting something in the engine internals, take a look at b2World::Solve, right at the beginning the max body count of the island is set to the number of bodies in the world, as the comment says 'the worst case'. Somewhere in the main loop that follows ('Build and simulate all awake islands') the loop variables are getting messed up is the only thing I can see would cause this. Dont change the world during collision callbacks if that's what you're doing.

Comment: If destroying body after I have detected a collision with a ContactListener qualifies as "changing the world after callbacks", then yes I am doing that.

Comment: okay, don't do that. In the ContactListener just make a list of all the things that collided, then after the world step is finished, process them as necessary. Anything that changes the world state should not be done during a world step: http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/removing-bodies

Comment: check out mye edit of the original post, how can I get outside the world step?

Comment: Yes, the DestroyBody call in your edit is outside the world step. But the collision callbacks occur within the Step, and I can't see what you're doing in them. Either way, the assert you mention only happens inside Step. Are you using multiple threads? Are you certain aMagnet.body is valid? From looking at the Box2D source code, there is no way the line you marked as causing the crash can cause the assert you initially mentioned. Are we talking two different crashes now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must scan for contacts, store all contacts in an array, and then AFTER all contacts have been checked, you remove your bodies.

Checking for contacts:

```
std::vector<MyContact>::iterator pos;
for(pos = _contactListener->_contacts.begin(); 
    pos != _contactListener->_contacts.end(); ++pos) 
{
    MyContact contact = *pos;

    b2Body *bodyA = contact.fixtureA->GetBody();
    b2Body *bodyB = contact.fixtureB->GetBody();

    // Rocket explosion rect
    if(bodyA->GetUserData() == NULL)
    {
        NSLog(@"NULL collision detected. (BODY A)");

        hasDoneRocketCollisions = YES;

        CCSprite *sprite = (CCSprite*) bodyB->GetUserData();

        if(sprite.visible == NO) continue;

        if(sprite.tag >= 200 && sprite.tag < 300)
        {
            index = sprite.tag - 200;
            if([spriteTracker containsObject:sprite]) continue;
            [spriteTracker addObject:sprite];
            bodiesToKill[counter] = bodyB;
            [enemyChargerIsAlive replaceObjectAtIndex:(int)(sprite.tag-200) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]];
            [ParticleController spawnExplosion:sprite.position inParent:currentDefaultNode];
        }
        else if(sprite.tag >= 300 && sprite.tag < 400)
        {
            index = sprite.tag - 300;
            if([spriteTracker containsObject:sprite]) continue;
            [spriteTracker addObject:sprite];
            bodiesToKill[counter] = bodyB;
            [enemyShooterIsAlive replaceObjectAtIndex:(int)(sprite.tag-300) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]];
            [ParticleController spawnExplosion:sprite.position inParent:currentDefaultNode];
            counter++;
        }
    }
}
```

Later in your method after all contacts have been checked:

```
b2Body *dyingBody;

for(int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
{
    CCSprite *dyingSprite;
    dyingSprite = [spriteTracker objectAtIndex:i];
    dyingSprite.visible = NO;

    // Is player projectile
    if(dyingSprite.tag >= 100 && dyingSprite.tag < 200)
    {
        CCParticleSystemQuad *dyingParticle;
        dyingParticle  = [particlesToKill objectAtIndex:particleIndex];
        particleIndex++;
        [dyingParticle stopSystem];

        dyingBody = bodiesToKill[i];
        dyingBody->SetActive(false);

        [ParticleController spawnExplosion:dyingSprite.position inParent:currentDefaultNode];
        [AudioController playExplosion];

        dyingSprite.visible = NO;

        if([_player currentShotType] == 1)
        {
            rocketHitBody->SetTransform(b2Vec2(dyingSprite.position.x/PTM_RATIO, dyingSprite.position.y/PTM_RATIO), 0.0);
            rocketHitBody->SetActive(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Take note that these are just random chunks of code I have copy and pasted in.  They are for example only and may only confuse you if you try to read them as exact instructions.

The point here is:  You can not remove a body while it is being accessed by the step or contact listener.  Finish using the contact listener and then remove your bodies.

Comment: check out the newest edit of the original post.. What is the problem there?

Comment: The problem is that the entire ContactListener::BeginContact is called from within the world's Step routine. Did you look at the diagram on my site? I could not explain it any clearer than that. The first part of Aaron's code goes in the contact listener. The second part goes in the main game loop, after the world's Step has finished.

Comment: My problem is that anywhere I put the "DestroyBody" within the main loop it crashes.. If I call it using a button it works perfectly and removes the body the ball collides with or has collided with earlier. How should I go about this?

Comment: Both of those code "chunks" are in the same method.  You have to finish iterating through your entire list of contacts before you remove any bodies.  Bodies are set to locked while contact listener is accessing them.  I have a -(void)scanForContact method that checks all reported contacts, and then when that is complete it goes through every body that I have stored and removes it (or in my case just sets it inactive).

Comment: Ok, thanks.. I will study your code and see if I can get mine working ;)

Comment: I added some comments to your second code chunk to try to make it more clear where the issue is.  You can not call to destroy a body while still inside the iterations.

Comment: Got it working now! Thank you so much for your kindness and patience.