# Delete all box 2D bodies from world in libGDX

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

Recently I have been trying to delete all my bodies from Box 2D world and I ran into a little bit of a trouble.

Here is my code for deleting all the bodies:

```
@Override
public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {

  if(keycode==Keys.R){

      LevelHolder.clearLevel();

  }

}

...

public static void clearLevel(){

    System.out.println("deleting bodies");
    Array<Body> bodies = new Array<Body>();
    world.getBodies(bodies);
    for(Body bod: bodies){
        world.destroyBody(bod);
    }
    System.out.println("deleted bodies");

}
```

And it seems like a reasonable peace of code to me however this crashes sometimes (the message "deleted bodies" never gets printed) with error message from native code:

```
Assertion failed: (m_bodyCount > 0), function DestroyBody, file /Users/badlogic/jenkins/workspace/libgdx-mac/extensions/gdx-box2d/gdx-box2d/jni/Box2D/Dynamics/b2World.cpp, line 133.
```

When deleting all bodies that I just got from the world Im somehow deleting more bodies than there are in the world. Also it doesn't happen all the time.

The piece of code is completely isolated and my game has no multi threading. So nothing could be deleting bodies while I'm stepping through all the bodies in the world.

What could be happening here? Maybe this is not the right way of deleting all the bodies and someone could give me an insight of how to do it better? Thank you.

Using libGDX 1.5.2 here.

Comment: What reference type is your object named world? If you wrote it, please post it for me to see.

Comment: I didn't write it. It is box2d's World class (from libgdx port)

Comment: Can you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of a disconnected snippet? Can we see what calls this function?

Comment: Did you take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6443832/game-crashes-when-i-try-to-destroy-a-b2body-what-should-i-do) and [here](http://www.box2d.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=6354)?

Comment: Kevin, how is this a disconected snipped? It gets bodies from world and than destroys them one by one. There are no references to classes that I have writen. Why would it matter what calls this method? It is completely isolated piece of code. Crash happens after printing message "deleting bodies" and before message "deleted bodies". User2016436, I took a look at the links but they don't seęm to be related to my problem.

Comment: @JustasSakalauskas I'm just trying to help, so I'm not sure why you've become defensive. The point is that we don't know whether the code calling this matters or not **because we can't see it**. It might matter if this is being called from a contact listener, for example. It's up to you how to proceed; I'm just trying to help you improve your question so it attracts more answers. Good luck.

Comment: @KevinWorkman I'm sorry if my comment came of as rude or defensive. Those were genuine questions of mine. A world locked error would show if I tried to delete bodies in contact listener so it seemed irrelevant to me. I updated my question, the method is called when input event fires. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I was using the same code as you to destroy all bodies and ran into a similar problem. I believe the problem is that you are trying to destroy bodies while your box2d.World is locked(you can check with world.isLocked()). During your world.step() your box2d.World is locked. This was my problem, as I was trying to destroy bodies as a result of a beginContact() event and couldn't because this was being handled within world.step().

My solution was to assign a boolean flag to true and just before doing world.step() i would check to see if it was true and if it was, then I destroy all bodies using same code as you did above.

Here is an example i tested:

```
private boolean destroyAllBodies;

public void clearBodies()
{
    destroyAllBodies = true;
}

public void update()
{
    if(destroyAllBodies)
    {
        Array<Body> bodies = new Array<Body>();
        world.getBodies(bodies);
        for(int i = 0; i < bodies.size; i++)
        {
            if(!world.isLocked())
                    world.destroyBody(bodies.get(i));
        }
        destroyAllBodies = false;
    }

    ...

    world.step(1/60f, 6, 2);

    ...
}
```

I hope that helped. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the count of bodies first, and then write a for loop that goes through the array using that count, rather than an enumerator. Editing a collection while it's being enumerated can cause issues.

Comment: Deleting body from the world doesn't delete the body from array. So the collection isn't edited in any way.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to delete the bodies in the keydown event so the world may be locked.
What you should do is delete them in the render method.

```
    boolean clearLevel=false;
        @Override
        public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
            if(keycode==Keys.R){
                clearLevel=true;
            }
        }

        ...

        public boolean render(float delta){
            world.step(delta, 8, 4);

            if(clearLevel){
                System.out.println("deleting bodies");
                Array<Body> bodies = new Array<Body>();
                world.getBodies(bodies);
                for(Body bod: bodies){
                    world.destroyBody(bod);
                }
                System.out.println("deleted bodies");
                clearLevel=false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: This is wrong. Render and Input events are synchronized.

Comment: I made a few games before and the way you are doing it makes the same error. And the code above is the way i make it work with out any problem. You must run the code after the world.step().

Comment: I tested your code before posting my comment and it doesn't work.